Rendering issues with Flatlist or other elements that include Scroll
I have an application with a tab system developed using Expo Router. Inside one of the tabs, I have configured a Redirect from the root path of the tab to a specific subpath. Below is the code involved:
import { Redirect } from "expo-router";

export default function Index() {
    return <Redirect href='/favorites' />
}

The favorites code is as follows:
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ScreenLayout from '../../../components/screen-layout/ScreenLayout'
import { FlatList, View } from 'react-native'
import { Stack } from 'expo-router'
import SwitchCategory from '../../../components/switch-category/SwitchCategory';
import { dataRealEstates, dataVehicles } from '../../../data';
import VehicleCard from '../../../components/vehicle-card/VehicleCard';
import RealEstateCard from '../../../components/real-estate-card/RealEstateCard';

export default function index() {

const [category, setCategory] = useState("VEHICLES");

const vehicles = dataVehicles.filter(vehicle => vehicle.fav);
const realEstates = dataRealEstates.filter(realEstate => realEstate.fav);

const getElements = (category, item = null) => {
    const elements = {
        VEHICLES: { data: vehicles, component: <VehicleCard item={item} /> },
        REAL_ESTATE: { data: realEstates, component: <RealEstateCard item={item} /> },
    };
    return { data: elements[category].data, component: elements[category].component };
}



return (
    <ScreenLayout withHeader>
        <Stack.Screen
            options={{
                headerShown: true,
                headerTitle: "Favorites",
                headerTintColor: "black",
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8",
                },
                headerBackTitle: "Back",
                headerShadowVisible: false
            }}
        />
        <SwitchCategory
            category={category}
            setCategory={setCategory}
            className="mt-2 mb-4"
        />

        <FlatList
            data={getElements(category).data}
            numColumns={2}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
            style={{ padding: 5, marginBottom: 20 }}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                getElements(category, item).component
            )}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 15 }} />}
            columnWrapperStyle={{ gap: 15 }}
        />
    </ScreenLayout>
)
}

When I navigate directly to the /favorites route from other tabs or get redirected to this route from the root of the tab using Redirect, I experience the following issues:
Constant flickering or re-rendering of items in the FlatList:
Rendered items (vehicle or property cards) appear to flicker or update unexpectedly.
Strange scrolling behavior:
Scrolling is not smooth, resets unexpectedly, or returns to the beginning when interacting with items. Inconsistent list interaction:
Sometimes, some items become unresponsive or the scroll state is not preserved when returning to the same screen.
Folder structure
I tried switching to ScrollView, optimizing the Flatlist using memo, separating the renderItem function using useCallback, but I get the same result

I just realized something, if I comment out the Stack.Screen code block, everything looks fine, the problem comes when I uncomment it, the list cuts off the last items. The code is this:
export default function index() {


const vehicles = dataVehicles.filter(vehicle => vehicle.fav);
const realEstates = dataRealEstates.filter(realEstate => realEstate.fav);

const getElements = (category, item = null) => {
const elements = {
    VEHICLES: { data: vehicles, component: <VehicleCard item={item} /> },
    REAL_ESTATE: { data: realEstates, component: <RealEstateCard item= 
      {item} /> },
    };
    return { data: elements[category].data, component: 
    elements[category].component };
}



return (
<View className="flex-1 h-screen py-3 px-4">
        {/* <Stack.Screen
            options={{
                headerShown: true,
                headerTitle: "Favorites",
                headerTintColor: "black",
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8",
                },
                headerBackTitle: "Back",
                headerShadowVisible: false
            }}
        /> */}
    
    <View className="flex-1 items-center">
        <FlatList
            data={getElements(category).data}
            numColumns={2}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
            style={{ padding: 5, marginBottom: 20}}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                getElements(category, item).component
            )}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 15 }} />}
            columnWrapperStyle={{ gap: 15 }}
            ListFooterComponent={<View />}
            ListFooterComponentStyle={{height:20}}
            />
    </View>
</View>
)
}

If I uncomment that block the FlatList scroll does not reach the bottom and cuts the last row:
Problem
